# How much power/intensity IR Diode should have to be seen from 30-50 meters

Tags: led, diodes, infrared

How much power/intensity IR Diode should have to be seen from 30-50 meters by camera with IR pass filter? Must be a good point in a photo. Should be seen in a day light. Preferably with wide angle.

About power supply: 2-4 AA accumulators, should work at least a hour :)

Camera: I think 2-3 megapixel should be enough? Maybe more.

Comment: I once did a little experimenting for long range laser tag, you need a lens to collimate the light, or you need more than one led if you really need wide angle. I'd deepen this wide angle thing a bit: you need to see a point as small as possible from an angle as wide as possible, is this right?

Comment: @VladimirCravero thanks for answer. i need to see a point as big as possible) so i can recognize it programatically) about wide angle: i need a big angle because this led could be in different positions so it shoud be visible from different sides of view. Maybe i shoud use more than one, i don't know really, so i asked a question here)

Comment: @VladimirCravero about size of point, it should recognizable size, not so big, not so small)

Comment: The question depends entirely on the camera, more megapixels does not mean better in this case, as you are only really interested in the sensitivity of the sensor.

Comment: @JohnU i think it will be enough, isn't is? http://www.ebay.com/itm/1pcs-MT9T112-MI-SOC3132-3-1Mp-HD-CMOS-Camera-Module-w-Adapter-Board-JPEG-Out-/271158917502?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item3f2254b97e

Comment: Impossible to know - that advert doesn't specify an actual sensitivity value. Compare the data sheet for something like a Sony FCB-EX985 camera block: http://pro.sony.com/bbsc/ssr/cat-camerasindustrial/cat-ciblockcameras/product-FCBEX985E/ which tells you some numbers like "Min illumination: 0.3 lx (typical) (F1.35, 50 IRE)" as well as lens characteristics. From this you can use SCIENCE to decide if it will detect the output of a given LED over a given distance for a given viewing angle...

Comment: @JohnU, would that be the minimum illumination required to be capture by the camera?

Comment: Do you have to use a camera for the detector?  Just thinking that with a photodiode and a blinking LED you could use synchronous detection... the lock-in thing.

Comment: There are a lot of unknowns here which should be easy to clear up.  First off, clarify what you are doing.  It sounds like you want to have a laser indicator or spot that is visible in ambient light? secondly, you will only be recording in the IR - correct? The next steps will involve understanding how well the camera works in the near IR and the F/# needed.  The QE (Quantum efficiency) of sensors drops off dramatically in the IR depending upon how they are made so this will be need to be tested _before_ you buy something.

Comment: @GeorgeHerold using photodiode i will only know what diode is in field, but i need to know where it is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be in luck. On eBay you can find 3-watt IR LEDs quite cheaply, such as [10pcs 3w 850nm infrared IR LED for night vision camera with 20mm Star PCB](http://www.ebay.com/itm/10pcs-3w-850nm-infrared-IR-LED-for-night-vision-camera-with-20mm-Star-PCB-/221431879504). Your AA cells must be long-life alkaline or NIMH rechargeables. Two AAs in series should drive a single LED with a 1.5 to 2 ohm limiting resistor for a couple of hours. And the resistor must be a 2-watt or higher. Yes, I know, it's grossly inefficient, but it's simple and ought to work without more electronics experience than I suspect you have.

Let's run a few numbers.

Let's say your camera field of view is 30 degrees. A single pixel is then 30 / 2048, or .015 degrees. At a range of 50 meters this covers about 13 mm, assuming perfect focus. Sunlight has a maximum intensity of about 1 kw / square meter, so the light reflected from a very white surface at one pixel will have a maximum power of about 0.17 watt total. IR makes up about 1/2 of sunlight's power, and let's say the camera response for a red pixel includes 20% of the visible and 20% of the IR. Then the overall red pixel power will be ~ .07 watt / pixel. Since the data sheet for the sensor which you gave has no data at all about the response in IR, this is purely speculation, but it's the best I can do. Certainly the camera can't see all that far into the IR. If it can, it will accept more IR power, which is bad for you.

Now think about the LED. Let's say that the LED has an efficiency of 20% - that is, it puts out .6 watt of IR. This is probably close. The emitter size is clearly less than a pixel, so you can compare it to the reflected sunlight. It will actually be somewhat higher than that if you are within the LEDs 135 degree field of view.

And the LED puts out about 9 times more power than the camera ought to see from reflected sunlight, assuming no specular surfaces. Like I say, you may be in luck.

If you go with a wider field of view, the pixel size increases, so the sunlight power/pixel increases, but the emitted LED power does not. So, for instance, going to a 60 degree field of view should cut your LED/sunlight ratio to about 2 to 1, which may or may not be adequate for reliable detection.

This is all very rough, and some of my assumptions may be off, but the numbers look close enough to warrant spending a few bucks on some LEDs. But don't go promising that you can make it work until you've actually tried it.

ETA - I thought I'd mention that the specific IR LED I linked to may not be acceptable. Without knowing the response of the camera, I'd recommend getting an LED as close to visible as possible.

Comment: Great answer! When determining that a pixel was 0.015 degrees for a 30-degree field of view, where did the "2000" figure come from?

Comment: The camera linked (via eBay) is 2048 x 1536, and I just rounded down to 2000. No sense in getting carried away with worrying about precision at this level of analysis. Eh, so I went and changed it.

Comment: Thanks, I see!  I agree that using 2000 is close enough :)

Comment: +1, that's a nice answer... maybe optimistic.  CCD's are sensitive into the IR, but they often put in a filter to block it.  You can take the filter out, or buy the cheaper model with the same ccd but no filter.  (if you can find one.)    If I was going to try and find an led at ~30m in sunlight, I'd just assume a lockin.  If you can access a few individual pixels and monitor them at some rate... and then if you blink the LED at a slower rate, (say ten times slower), then finding the led might be easier... if you also had access to the 'reference signal' that blinks the led..

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast thank for you answer. About some nubmers, you said resistor should be 1.5-2 ohm, 2-watt or higher. But using online resistor calculator and LED Specifications(1.4V, 700mA), 2 AA batteries(2.4V) it should be 1.5 ohm and 1W(not 2W), is it right?

Comment: I used http://www.powerstream.com/AA-tests.htm for numbers, and you'll note a fresh battery starts out at nearly 1.5 volts for current in the .5A to 1A range. Even with a 2-ohm resistor, that's an initial current of ~ 800 mA for a fresh battery, so I'd recommend a resistor more like 2.5 ohms. It's never a good idea to run any device over maximum. And starting power is about 1.12 watts, so the next normal rating above this is 2 watts.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast for example if i will use 2.4 om resistor. At the very start voltage will be 3V so in output will be .66A - 95% of LED power mentioned by you. When batteries will be in 2.4V output will be .042A - 60% of LED power, it is bad to lost 40% of light :) Can i do something to avoid this? thanks

Comment: @Kracken - You can, but you're going to have to learn a lot more about electronics first. You would need to make a constant-current source for the LED. This would keep the current through the LED constant until the battery voltage fell to a certain point. And doing this for a voltage this low is not simple. Please reread the last sentence of the first paragraph of my answer.